# Checking for linear dependence with basis family

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $B=(b1,b2,b3)$ be a basis of a vector space over the field $F$. I have to check for linear dependence for the following families: $$1:(b1+b2,b2+b3,b3+b1)$$$$2: (b1-b2,b2-b3,b3-b1)$$ $$3: (b1,b1+b2,b1+b2+b3)$$

Now I would have said that both 1 and 3 are linearly independent and 2 is linearly dependent, since $b1-b2 = -1(b2-b3)+ -1(b3-b1)$

What confused me a little bit is that there is a hint which tells me that for one of the families I have to distinguish between $Char(F) = 2$ and $Char(F) \neq 2$.

I know what the characteristic of a field is, but I do not quite understand where this would make a difference here. Any hints?

Comment: It matters in case 1.  The important thing about characteristic 2 fields is that addition and subtraction are identical.  Thus cases 1 and 2 are indistinguishable when $Char(F)=2$.

Comment: I see. So I guess case one is linearly dependent as well if $Char(F) = 2$. Thank you very much!